# Why can't I directly ls /dev/sda1

Tags: mount, devices, automounting

I have an external microSD card plugged into my machine via a USB stick. I believe it was auto-mounted because I can see

```
$ ls /media/me
7538-3DFD
```

I believe it is mounted to `/dev/sda1` because I see

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

...    

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVKW512HMJP-00000              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 00330861-D059-4F2E-8AAD-204F67A60293

Device           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem

...

Disk /dev/sda: 29.73 GiB, 31927042048 bytes, 62357504 sectors
Disk model:  Storage Device 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        8192 62357503 62349312 29.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

(where the ... moves past many entries for /dev/loop__)

Although I can do an ls on `/media/me/7538-3DFD` and see the files in that directory, I cannot directly do an ls on `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sda1`. All I see is either `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sda1`. Why is that? Is my MicroSD card mounted somewhere else? If so, why don't I see it with `fdisk -l`?

Comment: What do you expect to see when you run `ls /dev/sda` or `ls /dev/sda1`?

Comment: @ChrisDavies - I expected to see the same thing I see when I do `ls /media/me/7538-3DFD` - i.e. the files in that directory

Comment: Why? `/media/me/7538-3DFD` is a directory, `/dev/sda1` is a file. Why would `ls` have the same output for a directory and a file?

Comment: If you want to find out, or confirm, where a device is mounted, just run `mount` and look at the output -- if you don't want to scan manually, pipe to grep or similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda1` are "block devices" that simply read and write "disk blocks (clusters)".. When a block device is "mounted" (`man mount`), the device is interpreted by a "filesystem", and connected to the file system at `/media/me/7538-3DFD`.

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/sda1` is a special file that gives you access to a fragment of a block device, the fragment is a partition. In your case the device is your microSD card. `/dev/sda` gives you access to the entire card. With sufficient permissions you can read the partition or the whole card from the beginning to the end as a single data stream, a single "blob". With sufficient permissions you can write a data stream to the partition or to the whole card.

Your `/dev/sda1` partition contains a filesystem, the "blob" has some internal structure. It's kinda similar to a tar, rar or zip archive. Files, even directory trees can be written inside such archive along with metadata.

Normally you extract tar or zip. There are programs though that let you peek into such archives, get a single file, add files, modify maybe.

You can do something similar with a filesystem on `/dev/sda1`, except the program you use is (usually) the kernel itself with a proper filesystem driver. By mounting the filesystem at a mountpoint (`/media/me/7538-3DFD` in your case; your `/dev/sda1` is *not* a mountpoint), you gain convenient access to the "archive" the filesystem is. When you read or write files under the mountpoint, the kernel actually arranges reads from and/or writes to the "blob" you see as `/dev/sda1`; and it does it in a proper way, so the filesystem remains a valid filesystem of its type.

Still, like a tar file keeps being a tar file even if some program shows you the content, `/dev/sda1` keeps being the special file associated with the partition, even if its filesystem is mounted and in use. Don't expect a tar file or `/dev/sda1` to become a directory. In case of a mounted filesystem the mountpoint is *the* directory you need to use if you want to access files inside the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

- Entries in `/dev` are devices. You'll get (at least) one for each device associated with your system. For example, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda1`
- Directories under `/media` are filesystems, and are typically automatically mounted when you attach removable storage. For example, `/media/me/7538-3DFD`.